# Node global vs local module priority

Tags: node.js, npm

Can I use global node modules to override local node modules on certain environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what you mean by "certain environments". In any event, you never install modules globally in order to use them locally. It is technically possible if you have the global module folder in your NODE_PATH environment variable, but this is bad practice for many reasons, including that your code will now have a module resolution strategy that is undocumented and unpopular.